# How to render async content on React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm building a SPA based on WP API and want to render both posts and their featured images but they come in separate endpoints.

When rendering, React don't wait the request to resolve and get the error: "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])."

Totally a beginner about Promise and Async/Await functions. Don't even know if I'm using it correctly.

```
import React, { Suspense, Component } from "react";
import { FontSizes, FontWeights, PrimaryButton, DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import axios from "axios";
import './Home.styl'

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        posts: []
      }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

      this.renderPosts();

    }

    renderPosts() {

      axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://sextou.didiraja.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response)

        this.setState({
          posts: response.data,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))

    }

    async getImg(mediaId) {

      const getImg = axios
        .get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://sextou.didiraja.net/wp-json/wp/v2/media/17')
        .then((response) => {
          return {
            url: response.data.source_url,
            alt: response.data.alt_text,
          }
        })

      const obj = getImg

      return (
        <img src={obj.url} />
      )

    }

    render() {

      const { posts } = this.state

      return (
        <span className="Home-route">

        <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Sextou!</h1>

          <div className="events-wrapper">
            {
              posts.map((post, key) => {
                return (
                <div className="event-card" key={key}>

                  <img src={this.getImg()} />

                  <h2
                    className="event-title"
                    style={{ fontSize: FontSizes.size42, fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold }}
                  >
                    {post.title.rendered}
                  </h2>

                  {post.acf.event_date}

                  <span>{post.excerpt.rendered}</span>

                  <a href={post.acf.event_link} target="_blank">
                    <DefaultButton
                      text="Acesse o evento"
                    /> 
                  </a>

                  <a href={post.acf.event_ticket} target="_blank">
                    <PrimaryButton
                      text="Comprar ingressos"
                    /> 
                  </a>

                </div>

                )
              })
            } 
          </div>


        </span>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Home;
```

Comment: You need to handle rendering before the posts have been retrieved.

Comment: Your `getImg()` method is returning a node (`<img src={obj.url} />`) but you're calling it from the img `src` (`<img src={this.getImg()} />`). Would probably be better to just set that obj.url to state, and render it only when it has a value.

Comment: @sallf I pasted the wrong calling, even when I try calling `{this.getImg()}` gets the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fetch the images the same way as you fetched the posts:

Include them in your `state`

```
this.state = {
  posts: [],
  image: null
};
```

Call `getImage` in `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getPosts();
  this.getImage();
}
```

`setState` when the promise resolves:

```
.then(response => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    image: {
      url: response.data.source_url,
      alt: response.data.alt_text
    }
  }));
});
```

Display a loading screen or a spinner until the image loads

```
render() {

  const { posts, image } = this.state;

  if (!image) {
    return "Loading";
  }

  // ...
}
```

I would also advise using `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`, because `componentWillMount` [is deprecated and is considered unsafe.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Here's a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-render-async-content-on-react-s2ctp).

Comment: My final intent were images dynamic with the id from post BUT according to the code I pasted, this solves the problem. And it helped me finda my solution, so I checked as Solved! Thanks Istvan :)